# Can look up tables be used to store primary keys?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I am in the designing phase of the database which deals with online shopping. That is primarily stores, categories, products etc. The business consultant for the project has suggested to use Look up tables to store Primary Key. For example, if we want to fetch the next store Id it will be read from the look up table. I am not sure how this works with PK. After reading several posts on google, what I could understand is that values that are repeating continuously like Male/Female or Open/Closed are usually stored in look up tables. I don't get an idea on how to implement this in case of primary keys.

Any inputs or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way would be to ask your boss about what he/she meant exactly.  What makes this question a bit hard to understand for me is 'fetching' the next store ID - in which circumstances do you do that?

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to "normalization"?

Comment: Show some table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the idea behind this is to simulate sequences, which are lacking in MySQL. Such a table would have one row for each "sequence", containing the next ID value to be used for a particular table.

I would consider using auto-increment columns instead. However, using lookup tables to maintain ID values is a valid approach when you want more control over the generated values or to maintain non-numeric IDs.

Comment: It's generally frowned upon to use lookup tables to place in the PK. This due to the fact that you now have a table that needs to be looked at every time you want to add a value to one of your tables. In a high-volume database this tends to create locking. We have one in one of my databases and everyone who knows anything about databases (vendor database) basically wishes we could get rid of it.

Comment: I admire your generalisation based upon "one of your databases". Let us all frown upon those poor souls who don't know anything about vendor databases.

Comment: I had a brief discussion with him, and according to him it is to control the sequences as mentioned by mustaccio in the answer above. But can you explain what is benefit of this? Does this enhance performance?